# Add Basic Metadata to Wordpress Website

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, metadata, meta-tags, meta

I'm trying to add basic metadata to my Wordpress website. There is some metadata that's automatically generated for me, but I want to add custom metadata. To start I'd like to put metadata code around the phone number on my website. If anyone knows anything I'd greatly appreciate it!

My website is www.amigospanishcenter.com

Answer (score 0):

Which specific metadata are you trying to add? Are you talking about `schema.org` markup? Like this?

`<a href="tel:8765554321" itemprop="telephone">876-555-4321</a>`